# How to connect library apache HttpClient for Android 4.3.5 (GA)?

Tags: java, android, apache

I need sent a zip dirrectory to the server side

as far as I know I have to use

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();

            HttpPost uploadFile = new HttpPost("...");

            MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
            builder.addBinaryBody("file", new File("..."), ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, "file.ext");
            HttpEntity multipart = builder.build();

            uploadFile.setEntity(multipart);

            CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(uploadFile);
            HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
```

For this i need connect `library apache HttpClient for Android 4.3.5 (GA)`
i was googling and fond some samples how to connect, according that samples i need to add in my build file some lines

```
dependencies {
compile files('libs/mapquest-android-sdk-1.0.1.jar')
compile files('libs/osmdroid-android-3.0.8.jar')
compile files('libs/slf4j-android-1.5.8.jar')
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.5'
}
```

i have done it, but it still problem when i try add import in my class

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
```

stydio doesn't see this.

Comment: I suggest you use `OkHttp`. It's much simpler to use and has a good "recipes" page.

Comment: it is very weird, why google doesn't provide any native methods to sent a directory... in each case i should connect library, just for sent one directory...

Comment: as far as I know, `OkHttp` is now  apart of android sdk.

Comment: @LittleChild No... it's not a part

Comment: I think you are missing `compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5'` [Maven link](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient-android/4.3.5)

Comment: Thanks! It is really solve some of problem actually this HttpClients CloseableHttpClient ContentType CloseableHttpResponse, but it still a issue with HttpPost MultipartEntityBuilder HttpEntity ... Maybe you know what i should else to add?

Answer (score 1):

Eventually i added

```
compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4' to the build.gradle file
```

and

```
android {
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you add these in lib folder and also compile these in gradle

```
 compile files('libs/apache-httpcomponents-httpcore.jar')
 compile files('libs/httpclient-4.2.3.jar')
```

You used this for Http..
 httpclient-4.2.3.jar [Download Link For Httpclient-4.2.3.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/Downloadhttpclient423jar.htm)

apache-httpcomponents-httpcore.jar [Download Link for apche-httpcomponents](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadapachehttpcomponentshttpcorejar.htm)

You also add in Gradle these Lines

which handle the duplicate's files

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt' // will not include NOTICE file
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt' // will not include LICENSE file
}
```

Comment: i downloaded this libraries from your link, then i unzip them because they have `.jar.zip`, but for android studio we need `.jar` , and copy them to my project but it is a some kind of close(privat) file and i can't `add as a library`... Could you give me step by step advise how to implement it?

Comment: dear these are zip download extact it.. by win rar or winzip you get .jar file inside. it

Comment: of course, it is the issue because when i get this `.jar` and put it in my project it is looks like a some kind of close(privat) file and i can't `add as a library`...

Comment: Add in your build.gradle

packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt' // will not include NOTICE file
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt' // will not include LICENSE file
    }

Comment: Duplicate's of some file in both which occur some error.... You add these lines in build.gradle